# Нужно сделать так,что бы после функции print, возвращалось снова к переменной "a"

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

```
cat = ["Подписка", "Аренда"]
price = ["Подписка - 300 рублей, аренда - 20 рублей ",]
a = input("добро пожаловать в магазин Himera: ")
if a == "каталог":
    print("наш каталог товаров:" + str (cat))
if a == "цена":
    print("цена:" + str (price))
```

Comment: К какой из a И что далее должно происходить? А какие условия выхода?

Comment: Если пользователь вводит слово каталог,ему выдает массив из списка товаров ,а затем должно возвращать назад,что бы пользователь мог заново ввести нужный ему пункт

Comment: Что за каталог? Как он выглядит? Обновите вопрос, что бы там была необходимая информация.

Comment: Обновил информацию

Answer (score 0):

Для примера, как можно сделать запрос информации от пользователя постоянно, до получения команда выхода:

```
catalog = {
    'qwer': ['1', '2'],
    'asdf': ['3', '4']
}

while True:
    a = input('Введи раздел каталога: ')
    if a == 'exit':
        break
    if a in catalog:
        print(f'Содержимое каталога {catalog[a]}')
    else:
        print('Такого раздела нет')
```